# .EOT font not displaying in IE8 and below

Tags: css, internet-explorer, fonts, font-face

this is driving me crazy for over a week, so I'll appreciate any help.

Im trying to import a custom font into my webpage. I'v donde it a thousand times, but this time i dont get it to work into IE 8 and below.

my css code is:

```
<style>
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Bello-Script';
    src: url('fonts/Bello-Script.eot?');
    src: url('fonts/Bello-Script.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fonts/Bello-Script.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fonts/Bello-Script.ttf') format('truetype'), 
         url('../fonts/Bello-Script.svg#Bello-Script') format('svg');

    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
</style>
```

HTML code:

```
<div style="font-family:'Bello-Script', Verdana">the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</div>
```

you can check it working here: https://metrikstudios.com/want/fbapp/font-test.php

Generally I convert to .EOT through fontsquirrel, however this font is blacklisted. I bought the complete commercial liscence, but they dont have a .EOT for sale.

So I'v used all the converters I found to create the .EOT, however I have not been able to display the font in IE8. Therefore im guesing that the problem is not the .EOT file, but something else.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If the font is blacklisted at FontSquirrel, the usual reason is that the rightholder of the font does not allow it to be used as a web font. If you have bought a license that allows such use, contact the vendor. If not, don’t use it. A license allows web font usage only if it explicitly says so or explicitly allows any use. It is possible that IE disallows the use of the EOT font because it checks usage rights.

Answer (score 0):

Just solved the problem, hope it helps someone:

It was the .eot file that was not working. You can check it working correctly right now at the link shown before:
 https://metrikstudios.com/want/fbapp/font-test.php

Made the .eot with microsoft weft and it worked correctly.